# How does std::map provide a constant size() operation?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I know all containers provide a constant `size()` operation, except `forward_list`. But how can `map`, whose internal data structure is red-black tree, provide `size()` in constant complexity? Same for others like vector and string. Do they use a counter? If so, why doesn't `forward_list`?

I am confused when I read the book *The c++ standard library: a tutorial and reference*.

Comment: They typically keep a counter member variable updated. So when asked for their size, they do not need to traverse the container, they simply look at the counter. Note that it is not specified **how** they need to implement it, just that it is a constant time operation.

Comment: why does not forward_list keep a counter member?

Comment: I think it's because it supports constant time splicing. You cant have constant time size and constant time splice. IIRC before C++11, std::list had O(1) splice, O(N) size. With C++11 it has O(N) splice, O(1) size. My guess is they made forward list have O(1) splice, in case someone needed this functionality.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157164/why-isnt-stdlist-size-constant-time

Answer (score 64):

This is a long and twisted story. :-)

Yes, map, set, list, etc. keep counters to supply a constant time `size()`.  Prior to C++11, none of the containers were required to keep counters, as their `size()` *should* be constant time, but not *shall* be constant time.  In the standard, "should" means maybe, maybe not, and "shall" means definitely.

In practice, in C++98/03 all containers had a constant time `size()`, except for `list`, even `map` and `set` (by using a counter).  This made for some horribly non portable code using `list`, some of which assumed a constant time `size()`, and some of which assumed a constant time ["splice some from other."](http://howardhinnant.github.io/On_list_size.html)  Both of those operations can not be constant time, implementations had to choose one or the other.

In C++11, the standard was changed to say that `size()` must be constant time.  However `forward_list` was also introduced at the same time.  And the whole point of `forward_list` is to be an optimization of `list`.  And the committee did not want to repeat the mistake of `list::size()`, sometimes being constant time, and sometimes being linear time.  So the decision was to not give `forward_list` a `size()` at all.  Thus clients would never fall victim to an unexpected linear time `size()`.  Clients of `forward_list` who want to do that computation still have `distance(fl.begin(), fl.end())` at their disposal if they should choose to do so.

See [N2543](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2543.htm) for more details on the rationale for omitting `size()` from `forward_list`.

Comment: I never did quite understand why the size after a splice could not simply be stored as -1 or such, where the size() member function would calculate it if needed. This would make for a constant time size(), except that it would be lazily re-evaluated after a splice, rather than eagerly as I believe the standard currently requires. And it would mean splice could be O(1) as long as the list's size is unused. It seems to me like the best of both worlds. What am I missing?

Comment: @hvd: As a std::lib vendor I investigated this possibility and discarded it as the worst of both worlds. It complicates every size-altering member of `list`, including 2 out of the 5 `splice` cases.  It also degrades the equality operators and `resize`. And it has a worst-case scenario involving alternating calling `size()` with "splice some from other."

Comment: The only reasonable solution I found to this dilemma was that proposed in http://howardhinnant.github.io/On_list_size.html, and the committee viewed it as too error prone. This proposal would have given the client a way to make all 5 forms of splice O(1).  4/5 are already O(1). This proposal made the last 1/5 O(1).

Comment: It would complicate every size-altering member of `list`, sure. The constant time operations would still happen in constant time, but the constant would become bigger. That's a fair argument against it. But I don't think it degrades the equality operators, or `resize`: they could call `size()` just as they currently can, which would usually be O(1), except after a splice. Nor would the worst-case scenario be a problem: that already requires an update of the size after each splice operation in the current standard, and that update would merely be moved from the splice to the size operation.

Comment: But I do like the proposal to specify the size on splice. I agree that it's too easy to get wrong, and I'm glad it didn't make it into the standard, but it's a creative attempt at a solution that could have worked.